# Is there any way to set 4th tab More tab in UITabBarController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have 6 tabs in my iOS app. and i need to set 4th tab as more and show 3 tabs as table in 4th tab. Is there any simple way to do this. to tell iphone-sdk to treat 4th tab as last tab and as "more" ?

Comment: If you add more than 5 tabs iOS will create the More tab as the 5th and add the More screen for you. Are you saying you only want 4 tabs to show before this happens?

Comment: [May be this will help you](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=iphone+how+to+add+more+tab+in+UITabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Make your 4th tab be this:

```
[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:0];
```

Comment: Hi, I want to handle the rest of the 3 tabs on this 4th tab , this makes it look loke more tab. but it does not handle rest of the tabs in uitableview. Is there any work around for same